# Reload XML resource file at startup

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I seek a little bit of advice...

I have an WPF C# program with an XML resource file in which I have text for some buttons, like a language file (let's call it language.xml), and 2 xml more, for example english.xml and spanish.xml.
I have the XmlDataProvider pointing to language.xml
At startup I seek in a database which language has the user in his/her configuration, and I overwrite language.xml with the content in english.xml or spanish.xml

Sometimes the program loads right, but most of the time it loads the wrong data, although you look in the language.xml and the data is right.
(When I say wrong data I mean loading the program and entering with one user with a language set, closing, and entering with another one with other language...).

It's a little bit confusing, but I hope someone have tried something like this...

Thank you in advance.  :)

Comment: I'm curious, why not just get english.xml when needed instead of getting english.xml and overwriting another and than using that one...?

Comment: That was the original plan, but I couldn't change the XmlDataProvider source depending on the value in the database. Maybe some kind of datatrigger in the xaml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug and see exactly where things get initialized ?

It would be quite simpler to have just set the language and point to the correct xml file rather than your language.xml file.You already have two language files so why do do need additional operations ....

Try to simplify and then see if you still get the proplem.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is in synchronization. 
As example, your program begin request to database, and starts UI. XmlDataProvider is created with old xml source, then (on service response) language.xml is rewritten with new value.

More details or code parts will help to understand your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. I had to reload the XmlDataProvider in the Loaded method. 
In addition, seeing that I had to reload the XmlDataProvider itself, I set it to point directly to the correct .xml file. :)

Thank you for your answers!